# Looking for a .tag file syntax highlighter in SublimeText 3

Tags: tags, sublimetext

Is there any plugins package for highlighting the syntax for .tag files in SublimeText 3?

Thanks

Comment: For example to highlight something like this: 

<c:if test="${pageId =='resetpasswordpage'}">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="${commonResourcePath}/css/reset.css"/>
</c:if>

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. In fact a plugin is not needed for this.
Just change the file type in sublmeText as follow:

[image]